# How to target multiple frameworks in VS2017 final?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

For ASP.NET Core I could target multiple frameworks (for example `netcoreapp1.1` and `dnx451`) in one Project.json:

```
"frameworks": {
   "netcoreapp1.1": {
     "dependencies": {
       "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
         "version": "1.1.0",
         "type": "platform"
       }
     },
     "imports": [
       "dotnet5.6",
       "portable-net45+win8"
     ]
   },
   "dnx451": {}
 },
```

In the final Version of Visual Studio 2017 I can only target either `netcoreapp1.1` or `dnx451`, but I see no way to target both.

I tried editing the csproj-file directly to add a 2nd Framework by Setting either `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1;dnx451</TargetFramework>` or even  `<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.1;dnx451</TargetFrameworks>` but get Errors in Visual Studio due to unsupported frameworks.

So how Do I target both `netcoreapp1.1` and `dnx451` in one project in the final version of Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Have you tried adding a second `TargetFramework` element? So `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework><TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>`?

Comment: dnx is a deprecated moniker (it was deprecated when RC2 came) iirc as RC1 was the last release which supported DNX. RC2 and upwards only run with the new dotnet tooling. You should use `netxxx` instead

Comment: I found this issue to provide more detail on the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747977/how-do-you-multi-target-a-net-core-class-library-with-csproj

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There will be a few things you need to change. First the `<TargetFrameworks>` tag is the correct one for multi targeting and `;` is the separator.

DNX was deprecated during development of RC2, so last version which supported DNX was RC1. The `dnxcore5x` (and later `dotnet5.x`) moniker got replaced with `netstandard1.x` (for Class libraries) and `netcoreapp1.x` for applications. `dnx4xx` got deprecated as a whole and `net4xx` should be used.

Additionally, when you target .NET Framework (alone or with .NET Core/NetStandard), you will need to define a runtime identifier:

```xml
<RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

or

```xml
<RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

Or whichever you want to be the default.

#### Update

Just as an additional information. When you target more than one platform, you need to use conditionals for package resolution, i.e. `Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == '<targetmoniker>'`

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp1.1'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App">
      <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Otherwise you may get package restore errors

Comment: So correct would be for example `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;net462</TargetFrameworks>` for a class library?

Comment: Yeah. But a common workaround for EF Core Tools was to set class library also to `netcoreapp1.x` because otherwise the tools wouldn't find the DbContext which is outside of the ASP.NET Core application (common practice to put DbContext in a class library). Dunno if this was fixed in the new tooling, but it was a limitation on VS2015 with project.json and the .NET Core Tools for VS, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#preview-2-known-issues

Comment: @Dismissile: So far yea. But there was no UI for most of the project.json settings neither

Comment: @Tseng true, but I was hoping that would be fixed by the VS2017 release :(