# How do you specify different dependencies and symbols when multi targeting a .NET Standard class library?

Tags: .net-core, appsettings, .net-standard

With `project.json`, it was possible to target different target frameworks, specifying different dependencies and conditional compilation symbols for each target framework.

I need to do the same thing with a .NET Standard class library using the `.csproj` project format. I know [how to target multiple frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747977/how-do-you-multi-target-a-net-core-class-library-with-csproj), but how do you specify different dependencies and conditional compilation symbols for each?

(In case "conditional compilation" is not clear, I need the ability to specify preprocessor directives in code such as `#if NET452`.)

A good example where this is useful is when dealing with appsettings. With the full .NET Framework, you need to reference `System.Configuration.dll` and work through `ConfigurationManager`. [.NET Core configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration) is a totally different beast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The accepted answer from your previous question which you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42787747/41071) already has the answer: use `<ItemGroup>`s with `Condition`s testing for `$(TargetFramework)`. Slightly modified code from that answer:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452'">
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB" Version="1.12.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard1.6'">
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core" Version="1.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

For preprocessor directives, you don't need to do anything. Directives like `NET452` or `NETSTANDARD1_6` are defined automatically.