# The 'Publish' target is not supported without specifying a target framework

Tags: msbuild, asp.net-core, publish, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.6.2

Using Visual Studio 2017, I created an ASP.NET Core site using .NET Framework.
(I do not have a `project.json`, I have a VS2017 project with `.cproj`)

My target is x64 Windows 2008R2. The beginning of my `.cproj` looks like follow:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" ToolsVersion="15.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net462</TargetFrameworks>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
```

However, and while I am targetting .NET 4.6.2 only, when I try to publish I am getting this error

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\buildCrossTargeting\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(31,5): Error : The 'Publish' target is not supported without specifying a target framework. The current project targets multiple frameworks, please specify the framework for the published application.

While looking for solutions online, I encountered people having the same problem but they actually have many targets, however, in my case I am not sure why I am even getting it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There was a change in the `.csproj` template (https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/251).
Instead of `<TargetFrameworks>` you need to use `<TargetFramework>`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
   <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Wow. Never would have found that without your post.

Comment: This information may now be out of date. I believe that `TargetFrameworks` (plural) has made a comeback. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747977/how-do-you-multi-target-a-net-core-class-library-with-csproj

Comment: @tjrobinson you should use `TargetFrameworks` if you need to support more then one framework, otherwise use `TargetFramework` or you will see `Your project targets multiple frameworks.` error  when running app (like `dotnet run`)

Comment: Why can't it look at the list, see that you have only one framework listed and then behave as per the `TargetFramework`?