Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.dll' or one of its dependencies
I'm currently developing a custom activity for SQL Server Bulk Insert using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient version 4.1.0.
Encountering a confusing issue, let me elaborate. I'm including the project DLL via NuGet package and adding the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient version 4.1.0 in the Edit Dependencies of NuGet.
Here are some key points to note:

My activity requires a connection string as input for establishing a connection.
I'm utilizing the Class Library (.NET Framework) project for activity development.
Transitioning the activity from legacy to Windows environment.(4.6.1 to .NET 6.0+)
The legacy activity operates smoothly without any issues.

Now, let's discuss the scenarios within UiPath Studio:

When UiPath.Database.Activities package is not installed.
In this scenario, I simply add my package and utilize the activity. However, upon execution, I encounter the following error:

Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)


When UiPath.Database.Activities package is installed (maintaining the same Microsoft.Data.SqlClient version 4.1.0).
Even after installing the package and running my activity, the same error persists.

When connect to Database Activity is used.
In this scenario, I employ the Connect to Database Activity without configuring it, simply providing the same connection string in the connection string field and choosing to provide to System.Data.SqlClient. Surprisingly, following this, my activity works without encountering any issues.


The issue at hand has led me to explore various solutions:

Verifying the files of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x84.dll in the output directory of the DLL file after building the project from Visual Studio.

Attempting to add all packages shown in the UiPath.Database.Activities package in the Edit Dependencies of NuGet package explorer, alongside their respective versions.
Image

Adding Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in the edit dependencies.

Manually adding Microsoft.Data.SqlClientx64.SNI.dll in my UiPath project root directory for testing purposes.

Comparing the packages inside Microsoft.Data.SqlClient version 4.1.0 for UiPath and mine.


UiPath.Database
and mine
Custom
Despite exploring these solutions, I remain puzzled as to why the same packages work seamlessly for UiPath activities but encounter issues with mine. Additionally, the dependency of my activity on the Connect to Database activity for execution adds to the confusion.
My code
public class DataTableToSQLTable : CodeActivity
{
     [Category("Input")]
     [RequiredArgument]
     [Description("Datatable to push into SQL table.")]
     public InArgument<DataTable> SourceDatatble { get; set; }

     [Category("Input")]
     [RequiredArgument]
     [Description("Datatable columns name that map with SQL table columns.")]
     public InArgument<string[]> SourceColumns { get; set; }

     [Category("Input")]
     [RequiredArgument]
     [Description("The connection string used to establish a database connection.")]
     public InArgument<string> connectionString { get; set; }

     [Category("Input")]
     [RequiredArgument]
     [Description("SQL table name.")]
     public InArgument<string> SQLTableName { get; set; }

     [Category("Input")]
     [RequiredArgument]
     [Description("SQL table columns name that map wih datatble columns.")]
     public InArgument<string[]> DestinationColumns { get; set; }

     protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
     {
         DataTable table = SourceDatatble.Get(context);
         string[] sourceColumns = SourceColumns.Get(context);
         string[] destinationColumns = DestinationColumns.Get(context);
         string connectionString = this.connectionString.Get(context);
         string sqlTableName = SQLTableName.Get(context);

         // Check if the source and destination columns match in length.
         if (sourceColumns.Length != destinationColumns.Length)
         {
             throw new Exception("The number of source columns does not match the number of destination columns.");
         }

         try
         {
             // First, try to open a connection to the database to ensure that our connection string is valid.
             using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
             {
                 connection.Open(); // Attempt to open the connection.

                 if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("Successfully established a connection to the database.");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     throw new Exception("Failed to establish a connection to the database.");
                 }
             }

             // If connection is successful, proceed with the bulk insert operation.
             using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
             {
                 for (int i = 0; i < sourceColumns.Length; i++)
                 {
                     sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("[" + sourceColumns[i] + "]", "[" + destinationColumns[i] + "]");
                 }

                 sqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600; // You can adjust this value based on your requirements.
                 sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[" + sqlTableName + "]";
                 sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             // It's often useful to provide more specific exception handling.
             // For example, you might want to handle SqlException differently to give more detailed DB error messages.
             throw new Exception($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}", ex);
         }
     }
}

Uipath Connect to Database activity code
using System;
using System.Activities;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using UiPath.Database;
using UiPath.Database.Activities;
using UiPath.Database.Activities.Properties;

[LocalizedDescription("Activity_DatabaseConnect_Description")]
public class DatabaseConnect : AsyncTaskCodeActivity
{
    private readonly IDBConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;

    [DefaultValue(null)]
    [LocalizedCategory("ConnectionConfiguration")]
    [RequiredArgument]
    [LocalizedDisplayName("Activity_DatabaseConnect_Property_ProviderName_Name")]
    [LocalizedDescription("Activity_DatabaseConnect_Property_ProviderName_Description")]
    public InArgument<string> ProviderName { get; set; }

    [DependsOn("ProviderName")]
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    [LocalizedCategory("ConnectionConfiguration")]
    [LocalizedDisplayName("Activity_DatabaseConnect_Property_ConnectionString_Name")]
    [LocalizedDescription("Activity_DatabaseConnect_Property_ConnectionString_Description")]
    public InArgument<string> ConnectionString { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(null)]
    [DependsOn("ProviderName")]
    [LocalizedCategory("ConnectionConfiguration")]
    [LocalizedDisplayName("Activity_DatabaseConnect_Property_ConnectionSecureString_Name")]
    [LocalizedDescription("Activity_DatabaseConnect_Property_ConnectionSecureString_Description")]
    public InArgument<SecureString> ConnectionSecureString { get; set; }

    [LocalizedCategory("Output")]
    [DependsOn("ProviderName")]
    [LocalizedDisplayName("Activity_DatabaseConnect_Property_DatabaseConnection_Name")]
    [LocalizedDescription("Activity_DatabaseConnect_Property_DatabaseConnection_Description")]
    public OutArgument<DatabaseConnection> DatabaseConnection { get; set; }

    public DatabaseConnect()
    {
        _connectionFactory = new DBConnectionFactory();
    }

    internal DatabaseConnect(IDBConnectionFactory factory)
    {
        _connectionFactory = factory;
    }

    protected override async Task<Action<AsyncCodeActivityContext>> ExecuteAsync(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string connString = ConnectionString.Get(context);
        SecureString connSecureString = ConnectionSecureString.Get(context);
        if (connString == null && connSecureString == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(UiPath_Database_Activities.ValidationError_ConnectionStringMustNotBeNull);
        }

        if (connString != null && connSecureString != null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(UiPath_Database_Activities.ValidationError_ConnectionStringMustBeSet);
        }

        string provName = ProviderName.Get(context);
        DatabaseConnection dbConnection = null;

        try
        {
            dbConnection = await Task.Run(() => _connectionFactory.Create(connString ?? new NetworkCredential("", connSecureString).Password, provName));
        }
        catch (Exception arg)
        {
            Trace.TraceError($"{arg}");
            throw;
        }

        return delegate(AsyncCodeActivityContext asyncCodeActivityContext)
        {
            DatabaseConnection.Set(asyncCodeActivityContext, dbConnection);
        };
    }
}


Why do you care about version?  SQLClient is usually backward compatible so if you install latest version it should work.  When I have issue with versions in c# what I normally do is to use VS Solution Explorer and in References delete the library.  Than using Project Menu add the Reference back to the project and do a clean build.  When adding the Reference VS will automatically locate the newest version and add back to project.  I would make a backup before trying just incase something goes wrong.

@jdweng yes but when im trying to add the latest Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.2.0 .in VS (project .NetFramwork) im getting error
Could not install package 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.runtime 5.2.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Release notes (https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/main/release-notes/5.2/5.2.0.md) says 5.2.0 is supported on Net 4.6.1.  Try a clean build and see what happens.  I think you need to install Net 4.6.1 on the machine.

See following for latest updates https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/commits/main/  Post issues here : https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues

Try adding https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI/

@jdweng thanks for the solutions , but unfortunatly none of them are working


Trying to add 5.2.0 after clean build but failed and gave the same error , (Unknown how to add multiple targetframework for v4.6.1) , i want to add Net6.0+


Tried updating the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI  from 4.0.0 to 4.0.1 (also tried to upgrade it to 5.2.0, faled due to same framework issue), meanwhile added Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI 4.0.1 in the dependencies of npm, both of them didnt work



@jdweng Also, an interesting point I neglected to mention is that with the UiPath.Database.Activities package version 1.6.1 (the current latest being 1.7.1), the older dependency of System.Data.SqlClient v4.8.2 was utilized instead of Microsoft. Surprisingly, this configuration functions properly within a Windows (.NET 6.0) project. However, when I employ it with the same dependency, it doesn't seem to function as expected, giving me error of unable to load dll 'System.Data.SqlClient'

Open the csproj file with notepad and look for duplicates : Unknown how to add multiple targetframework for v4.6.1

@jdweng sorry for the late reply, but i tried all the thing you mentioned, but its not working the same thing again

The error is in the csproj file.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747977/how-do-you-multi-target-a-net-core-class-library-with-csproj

@jdweng Thanks for that even i find a way to migrate this activities to .net6.0 but after doing modicfication im not being able to use the activity in uipath at all , please see this code https://collabedit.com/6mkm4 , also the docs  i have used https://docs.uipath.com/sdk/other/latest/developer-guide/migrating-activities-to-net

@jdweng This is snippet of what im able to see in uipath https://imgur.com/a/rWa0ChY, also this is the code shown in uipath
"Could not find type 'Sql_Bulk_Insert__Devesh_.DataTableToSQLTable' in assembly 'Sql Bulk Insert (Devesh)'. Row: 144, Column: 6"

I think error is due to two target frameworks : net461;net6.0-windows  You have conditional code in csproj for either net461 or net6.0-windows.  When you have both duplicates are being created.  SQL Client is being added twice : ..\packages\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.4.1.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll

@jdweng I tried this two but it showing me an error , i even tried to create a .net4.6.2 project in vs which supported by Microsoft.Data.SqlClient v 5.2.0 , but that is having some diffrent issue
here is the error when i build with 4.6.1 with chnages https://collabedit.com/r2fxu

@jdweng Same error for net4.6.2 when used SqlClient v5.2.0 , as net4.6.1, 
..\packages\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.5.2.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll


The best way of fixing these issues is in VS use Solution Explorer.  Delete the Reference and then add back.  The version should automatically select one that is on the machine.  When using 4.6.1 the dll is built on Net 4.0 and you do not have Net 4.0 installed on machine.  I would only have for TargetFrameworks one version instead of having two.  You can also move the HintPath out of the conditional section so it doesn't apprear twice.

@jdweng "The best way of fixing these issues is in VS use Solution Explorer. Delete the Reference and then add back."
u mean the SqlCient one ?, i removed it and now when im adding through manage package then i have this error https://collabedit.com/egtws, note this is net4.6.2 project and i was using SqlClient5.2.0 and after removing the existing one im also adding the same version and not 4.1.0

Try a clean build.  It looks like the SQL version needs Net 4.0.  Not sure why.  That is why I'm thinking you need a clean built.  One of the obj files is using Net 4.0.

@jdweng Still the same error after clean the project and rebuild, also i tried just the Class Library with .net6.0 LTS , even with this im getting initial error of SNI in uipath, idk what im missing out

the original error was "Unknown how to add multiple targetframework".  That need to be fixed in the csproj file.  You should only have one targetframework in the csproj file.

@jdweng nope not that it's the missing sni dll file error that occurred in uupath

@jdweng also now I'm trying to make this activity from scratch in a new project settings that is supported by uipath for making custom activity for .net6.0 + , more about it here https://docs.uipath.com/sdk/other/latest/developer-guide/creating-activities-with-code. , let's see if this can work

@jdweng also can you try to move this conversation to chat ? ,i don't have enough reputation for doing that ,not sure if it allows you to move it due to my lwo reputation, just try once

@jdweng BINGO !! , it just simply worked with the new template sdk project i mentioned above, i didnt even installed the uipath.database.activiies package in uipath, just only my package

Compare the new csproj file with old.

@jdweng yes i will and let you know

@jdweng I have this 3  projects in the new tempate project https://collabedit.com/92jmm , idk which one to compare with the old one , where two of them are main in process of creating activity

I took a quick look.  I think issue in the last two csproj has to do with 

@jdweng Thank you so much to stay on this topic and helping me out , really glad to have people like you guys on such platforms
